# NetfilterQueue refusing packet using scapy

Tags: python, soap, scapy, netfilter

I am trying to make a firewall for SOAP packets, I am using NetfilterQueue to intercept the packets, I only validate the packets that contain the actual SOAP request, however the NetfilterQueue function pckt.drop() doesn't alert the client that the request has been refused, in this case the client keeps re transmitting the packet, I tried to send an HTTP 403 error but it didn't effect the process as if the client didn't receive it at all, may be I did something wrong, I would be very thankful if someone could help me out, here is my python script:

```
from scapy.all import *
from netfilterqueue import NetfilterQueue
from scapy.layers import inet

def isSOAP(pkt):
    message=str(IP(pkt.get_payload())[TCP].payload)
    if(len(message)>0 and message.find("xml")>-1 and message.find("soap")>-1):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def check_signatures(pkt):
    if (isSOAP(pkt)):
        message=str(IP(pkt.get_payload())[TCP].payload)
        if is_attack(message):
            print "detected as attack"
            log_attack(pkt)
            pkt.drop()
            send_403(IP(pkt))
        else:
            print "normal message"
            log_normal(message,IP(pkt.get_payload()).src)
            pkt.accept()
    else:
        pkt.accept()

def send_403(pkt):
    AckNr=pkt[TCP].seq+len(pkt[TCP].payload)
    seqNr=pkt[TCP].ack
    port=pkt.sport
    html1="HTTP/1.1 403 OK\x0d\x0aDate: Wed, 29 Sep 2010 20:19:05 GMT\x0d\x0aServer: Testserver\x0d\x0aConnection: Keep-Alive\x0d\x0aContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\x0d\x0aContent-Length: 291\x0d\x0a\x0d\x0a<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\"><html><head><title>Testserver</title></head><body bgcolor=\"black\" text=\"white\" link=\"blue\" vlink=\"purple\" alink=\"red\"><p><font face=\"Courier\" color=\"blue\">-Welcome to test server-------------------------------</font></p></body></html>"
    ip=IP(src=pkt.dst, dst=pkt.src)
    TCP_SYNACK=TCP(sport=80, dport=port, flags="A", seq=seqNr, ack=AckNr)
    ANSWER=sr1(ip/TCP_SYNACK)
    data1=TCP(sport=80, dport=port, flags="PA", seq=seqNr, ack=AckNr, options=[('MSS', 1460)])
    ackdata1=sr1(ip/data1/html1)
    SeqNr=ackdata1.ack
    Bye=TCP(sport=80, dport=port, flags="RA", seq=SeqNr, ack=AckNr, options=[('MSS', 1460)])
    send(ip/Bye)

nfqueue = NetfilterQueue()
nfqueue.bind(1, check_signatures)
try:
    nfqueue.run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print
```

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this? Maybe a passive wireshark capture will help in finding out if the 403 error packet is correctly crafted and sent.

Comment: I didn't resolve this, I already tried to debug using wireshark, I noticed something odd, wireshark didn't recognize the packet that contains the HTML payload as an HTTP packet, it showed it as TCP. I abondoned this approach, I am using a hack to let iptables do the dirty work for me using --reject-with tcp-reset, not what I wanted but an easy solution.